# Отчеты на делфи

Tags: delphi

Подскажите как оформить отчет для бд на делфи?

Answer (score 2):

FastReports (www.fast-report.com/ru/) очень рекомендую, но он платный. Триальная версия(без ограничения времени) печатает только первые пять страниц отчёта с надписью в правом(?)-верхнем углу "Unregistered Version"

Comment: @Kyulix, у FastReport есть [бесплатный вариант](http://www.fast-report.com/ru/download/free-report-download.html) с отрытыми исходниками на базе старых версий.